# ngFor для обьекта

Tags: angular2, объекты

Обьект

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "borrower": null,
        "product": null,
        "passportData": null,
        "registrationAddress": true,
        "realAddress": true,
        "contactInfo": null,
        "workPlace": true,
        "lastWorkPlace": null,
        "incomeMonth": null,
        "outcomeMonth": null,
        "familyInfo": null,
        "familyInfoPassport": null,
        "propertyStatus": null,
        "loanPropertyAuto": null,
        "loanPropertyLand": null,
        "creditHistoryCurrent": null,
        "creditHistoryPast": null,
        "creditHistoryInfo": null,
        "guarantorInfo": null,
        "guarantorPassport": null,
        "guarantorContacts": null,
        "guarantorEmployment": null,
        "guarantorIncome": null,
        "guarantorOutcome": null,
        "guarantorExtendInfo": null,
        "partnerBank": null,
        "primaryChecking": null
    }
```

Необходимо вывести чекбоксы под каждое значение в объекте.
(null позже станут false, в данный момент просто не заполнено еще. так бек выдает)

Стандартно в ангуляр 2\4 не работает ngFor с обьектами такого рода. Ка понимаю нужно pipe. 
Создаю

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'keyValueFilter'
})

export class keyValueFilterPipe {
    transform(value: any, args: any[] = null): any {

        return Object.keys(value).map(function(key) {
            let pair = {};
            let k = 'key';
            let v = 'value';


            pair[k] = key;
            pair[v] = value[key];

            return pair;
        });
    }

}
```

Читаю документацию как добавить подключить пайп (ну ооочень многословно и информативно)

> You must include your pipe in the declarations array of the AppModule.
>   Собственно так и сделал. 
>   Далее.
>   Применяем в шаблоне

```
<li *ngFor="let u of productSettings | keyValueFilterPipe">First Name: {{u.key}} <br> Last Name: {{u.value}}</li>
```

Не работает.

> Error: Template parse errors: The pipe 'keyValueFilterPipe' could not
>   be found ("

пробовал еще создать модуль для данного пайпа, и подключать его в главный модуль, в компонент, все время данная ошибка.

Comment: _name: 'keyValueFilter'_ - то как это должно вызываться в разметке. Попробуй заменить свою разметку на `| keyValueFilter`

Comment: :D изначально так и было. но не работало это я уже сейчас  откатывался что бы тут выложить. да не до конца откатился) спасибо. заработало благодаря тому что в процессе гугления оказалось что нужно добавлять не в рут модуль а в тот к которому компонент привязан. в общем заработало. спасибо!

Comment: _не в рут модуль а в тот к которому компонент привязан._ - Не, добавлять надо в тот модуль, где объявлен сам pipe.

Comment: хотя действительно перенес в главный модуль и тоже работает. странно. но главное что работает. сейчас буду разбираться в чем была ошибка ранее. помимо того что вы написали. спасибо!

Comment: так. сейчас пощищу все и попробую разобраться. а то у меня он и как модуль подключен и просто пайп, и в рут и не в рут модуль. в общем каша.